# How to pass objects with stubbed methods in it_behaves_like to shared_examples_for block in rspec?

Tags: rspec

I have a spec like

```
describe MyClass do
  it_behaves_like SharedClass, MyClass.new
end
```

and in my shared example spec, I have

```
shared_examples_for SharedClass do |instance|
  before do 
    instance.some_my_class_method = double
  end
  # some specs here
end
```

There are few methods in MyClass instance that I cannot stub in the shared_examples_for block, so I want to stub them before passing it in it_behaves_like statement. like,

```
describe MyClass do
  before do
    @instance = MyClass.new
    @instance.stub(:my_class_method)
  end
  it_behaves_like SharedClass, @instance
end
```

but I cannot do that.It throws me
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `some_my_class_method=' for nil:NilClass

somehow I am not able to access that @instance object in the shared_examples_for context.
I am using ruby 1.9.3p392 and rspec (2.14.1)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the arguments you pass to `it_behaves_like` are evaluated at the time `it_behaves_like` is called, while the `before` block is evaluated just before the shared example is executed, which occurs at a later time. As a result, `@instance` as an argument is evaluated to `nil` and the formal parameter `instance` is assigned `nil`, resulting in your `undefined method` error.

I don't know of any easy way to do what you're trying to accomplish. One alternative shown in [this documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/example-groups/shared-examples#providing-context-to-a-shared-group-using-a-block) is to eliminate the formal parameter and require the caller to pass a block which uses `let` to establish the argument value, using some agreed to variable, as follows:

```
describe MyClass do
  it_behaves_like SharedClass {let(:instance) { MyClass.new }}
end

describe MyClass do
  it_behaves_like SharedClass do
    let(:instance) do
      myClass = MyClass.new
      myClass.stub(:my_class_method)
      myClass
    end
  end
end
```

In addition to being more verbose, however, this has the disadvantage that there is no implicit documentation within your shared example that it expects `instance` to set when it's called.

Although I've not seen it discussed anywhere, a somewhat hacky alternative would be have your shared example use the agreed-to-variable from the block if and only if the value of the formal parameter is `nil`, which could be defaulted for convenience. Unfortunately, you can't use the same variable for both, as the value of the parameter will always take precedence.

Comment: Since `let(:instance)` actually defines a method, you could actually use the same name for the let as you do for the `shared_examples_for` parameter (bare word).  Just call `instance()` instead of a bareword `instance` and it will know that you are referring to the method and not to the local variable...