# Enabling `let` to assign a formal parameter in case of block passed to RSpec shared example

Tags: ruby, rspec

In RSpec, one of the techniques for providing a value to a shared example is to use `let` to define a variable used by that example, as described in [this documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/example-groups/shared-examples#providing-context-to-a-shared-group-using-a-block).

Currently, the values passed into formal parameters take precedence over the any values established by `let`, as shown in the following example:

```
shared_examples_for "foo" do |x1|
  specify {puts [x1, x2, x3].inspect}
end

describe "" do
  let(:x1) {3}
  let(:x2) {3}
  let(:x3) {3}
  it_behaves_like "foo", 1 do
    let(:x1) {2}
    let(:x2) {2}
  end
end

# => [1, 2, 3]
```

My question is whether it would be possible/reasonable/desirable to change the RSpec semantics such that the variables set by `let` inside of the passed block would take precedence over the passed parameters and the above would output `[2, 2, 3]`. This would allow "simple" values to be passed in as parameters and more complicated values to be set via a block.

Comment: Could you come up with little more of a real world example for what you want? I would just use a `context` but can't make a case for it with your example above ;)

Comment: It came up when I was answering http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899204/how-to-pass-objects-with-stubbed-methods-in-it-behaves-like-to-shared-examples-f/20906206#20906206

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> use `let` to define a variable

`let` does not define variables; it defines a memoized helper method.  The distinction is important, as ruby treats variables and methods differently.  Specifically, local variables (e.g. the `x1` block arg in your `shared_examples_for` block) *always* take precedence over methods of the same name, unless you use `self.x1` to make it explicit that you are sending a message.

So, to answer your question: no, what you're asking is not possible.  I don't think it's desirable, either; having local variables always "win" when there is a name collision is super important for being able to reason about your code.  Consider the repurcssions if that was not the case.  Let's say you started with this code:

```
# in superclass.rb
class Superclass
end

# in subclass.rb
class Subclass < Superclass
  def do_something(name)
    # do something with the `name` variable
  end
end
```

At some future point, `Superclass` is updated to have a `name` method:

```
class Superclass
  def name
    "superclass name"
  end
end
```

If ruby did not give precedence to local variables over methods, the `Subclass#do_something` method would get broken by an unrelated change to `Superclass`.  The fact that local variables always take precedence means that you can more easily reason about what code does without worrying about changing in some distant code suddenly causing a particular identifier to be re-bound to a method rather than a local variable.

Comment: Thanks. Myron. Appreciate it as always, although it's scary to know you're still reading SO posts.  Lot of pressure, you know ...

Answer (score 0):

I would use `context`s if I just wanted to change the context a bit with new `let`s.

You can use `context` blocks inside or outside `describe` blocks. The are essentially the same but create a way for you to semantically organize your specs a differently (IMO better)

```
describe "adding a credit card" do
  let(:card_number) { "123456789012" }

  it "accepts cards" do
    pending
    # do something with card_number
  end

  context "failure" do
    let(:card_number) { "BLUEBEARD666" }

    it "doesn't handle weird formats" do
      # oh yeah!
    end
  end
end
```

In this case you have your embedded `let`s but it makes more sense semantically.

I hope this doesn't miss the point entirely :P

Comment: Actually, I really _was_ just interested in the `shared_examples` case. :-) Per my comment, I have no personal case to solve and the issue only came up in the context of answering another SO question. I assume that there are valid reasons to want to use shared examples which can't be addressed via a shared context (e.g. generic shared function to be used across multiple specs, etc.).

Comment: Yeah, I missed the boat on this and now understand more what you want - but have no answer. I will leave this answer though because your comment restates your intent in a nice way in case anyone else is as thick as me.